# How to create ionic 3 projects without downgrading ionic 4 cli

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have upgraded to ionic 4 but I would like to be to create ionic 3 projects without downgrading the CLI, please how do I go about it?

Comment: ionic 4 cli asks for the project version when you create new project.

Comment: Yes that is true but it doesn`t ask for cordova integrations anymore

Comment: In office on my work laptop I have Ionic 4. I cloned my Ionic 3 repo and just did npm install to pull all the dependencies. After that I was able to normally start working on it. I guess as long as your package json points to proper versions of Angular etc - you should be able to work with Ionic 3

Answer (score 3):

First create a new project using

```
ionic start projectname blank --type=ionic-angular
```

then you should use:

```
ionic cordova prepare android
```

to add cordova to the project.

Comment: What does this command do? How does it help OP? Add some explanation to your answers!

Answer (score 1):

ionic start projectname tabs --type=ionic-angular

Comment: This gives me what I need except it doesn`t add the cordova integration, doesn`t even ask anymore

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers noted, using `--type=ionic-angular` is the Ionic 4 CLI way of saying "Ionic 3".  Here's a reference to that: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3862

If you run `ionic start --list` it will show the available templates and project types. For project type,  `angular` would be Ionic 4, `ionic-angular` would be Ionic 3, and `ionic1` is actually well named :-)

```
name     | project type  | description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
blank    | angular       | A blank starter project
sidemenu | angular       | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
tabs     | angular       | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
tabs     | ionic-angular | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
blank    | ionic-angular | A blank starter project
sidemenu | ionic-angular | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
super    | ionic-angular | A starting project complete with pre-built pages, providers and best practices for Ionic development.
tutorial | ionic-angular | A tutorial based project that goes along with the Ionic documentation
aws      | ionic-angular | AWS Mobile Hub Starter
tabs     | ionic1        | A starting project for Ionic using a simple tabbed interface
blank    | ionic1        | A blank starter project for Ionic
sidemenu | ionic1        | A starting project for Ionic using a side menu with navigation in the content area
maps     | ionic1        | An Ionic starter project using Google Maps and a side menu
```